# I want to show fourier series by using matlab. help me.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

I want to show basic fourier series by using matlab.

I don't know where did I wrong please fix my code...

this code keeps making error in matlab.

```
function fv = f(x, N)

fv = 0;
for n=1:N
    fv = fv + (1/(2*n-1) *sin((2*n-1)*x);
end

x = 0:0.1:100;

N = 10;

plot(x, f(x, N))
```

I mean I wanna show
$f(x)= sin(x)+\frac{1}{3}sin(3x)+\frac{1}{5}sin(5x)+.....\frac{1}{2n-1}sin(2n-1)$ when n=10 into matlab code. help me.

Comment: This is just basic debugging. Try harder. You need to put in 2*n not 2n for example.

Comment: You don't even have matching parentheses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to simplify

I modified

```
t=0:0.001:10

k=0
for n=1:10

k=k+ (1/(2*n-1))*sin((2*n-1)*t)
end
plot(t,k)
```